# Same CaseId's appearing even i used distinct keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, sap-erp

Even i used Distinct Keyword but still im getting the Duplicate entries.

The code i used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(
       CONCAT(ekbe_bseg.mandt, ekbe_bseg.ebeln, ekbe_bseg.ebelp),
        CONCAT(ekbe_bseg.mandt, ekbe_bseg.bukrs, ekbe_bseg.belnr, ekbe_bseg.gjahr, ekbe_bseg.buzei)
        ) AS c_caseid
```

In the Output i'm getting multiple duplicate values. Quick help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` returns distinct _rows_. I.e. if you select several columns,  a column can contain duplicates.

Comment: Hi @jarlh, But i need Multiple columns data into one caseid, what should i do?

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer.